# How to configure and use SQLG with TinkerPop?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, tinkerpop3

I need a way to run graph queries on python django. TinkerPop and gremlin provide a way to run graph queries. How do i make them persistent. I have no idea about the java stack.

I tried the below commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge maven maven2 maven3
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:andrei-pozolotin/maven3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install maven3

git clone https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop.git
cd tinkerpop
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
bin/gremlin.sh

         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
gremlin> :q


git clone https://github.com/pietermartin/sqlg.git
cd sqlg
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

not sure what to do next.

how to run a gremlin-server that is configured with say a postgres database and connect to it from a python django web-app and execute queries like is-parent-of to check users permissions on the resource he is requesting?